# How many multiples of 6 are there from **1 to 200** which are not multiple of 4?

Tags: numerical-methods

Options:

1)16
2)17
3)19
4)15

How did we get that answer by solving??

Comment: How many multiples of $6$ are there? How many multiples of $12$ are there?

Comment: A number that is a multiple of 6 and at the same time a multiple of 4 is a multiple of...

Answer (score 1):

A number that is multiple of $4$ and $6$ at the same time must be multiple of $lcm(4,6)=12$.

This means that there are $$\left\lfloor\dfrac{200}{6}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\dfrac{200}{12}\right\rfloor =33-16 =17$$ multiple of $6$ and not multiple of $4$ between 1 and 200.

Answer (score 0):

By writing out a few terms you can see the formula for the elements of the sequence:

$$6,18,30,42,... \to a_n = 6 + 12n$$

(I wrote down the first few multiples of $6$, and took out the ones that were multiples of $4$.)

The largest value of $n$ that produces a value less than $200$ is $n=16 (a_n = 6 + 12(16) = 196)$.

Hence, there are $17$ elements ($n=0...16$).